# Unable to get TableCell to populate from custom class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm having a strange problem with my tableview that I'm not sure how to fix.  I've done this a dozen ways in a dozen programs and this is the first time it has not worked.

The issue is that I created a tableview in my application, created an object, sent the delegate and datasource to the object, referenced the object to my custom class and everything seems to work except the objectValueForTableColumn.

My object: 
[image]

My table:
[image]

The output:
[image]

The other programs I have written work exactly as intended but this one just won't return a value for the table column, even though I can see with my NSLogs that it is executing the code.  Instead I get the "Table View Cell" value for each cell just like you do when you don't return data.

h File: 
[image]

m File:
[image]

In this simple test I'm just wanting to verify it works by making every cell say "HELLO".

Log window:
[image]

My question is: can you look at this and tell me if I've missed something here?

Comment: Are you using a view-based table view?

Comment: Yes, I just dragged and dropped from the IB to my window so I ended up with the normal Bordered Scroll View -> Clip View -> Table View layout

Comment: Did you know that you can have cell-based and view-based table views? Check in Xcode that it's cell-based. I'm 90% sure this is not the probably because I don't think that view-based table view call `objectValueForTableColumn:...`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question.  It's a basic cell based table.

Comment: Did you include `- numberOfRowsInTableView:` ?

Comment: Yes, of course I did, as you can see from the output above.  Everything is working as expected except this noe thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up opening a ticket with Apple about this and they found a glitch in the Xcode that even though it was classified as a Cell based table it got changed to a View based table instead (but still showed in IB as cell based) and thus the values never populated.  They had me delete everything in that view and re-do it and then it started working as it should.

I had already tried deleting the table, but apparently that wasn't enough, I needed to also delete the view that the table was in and completly re-did my controller class for it as well.